# Как сделать поиск двух одинаковых чисел подряд в массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан массив с числами. Проверьте, есть ли в нём два одинаковых числа подряд.
Если есть - выведите 'да', а если нет - выведите 'нет'

Моё решение такое:

```js
var arr = [3, 1, 1, 12];
for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j > arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
      alert('yes')
    } else {
      alert('no')
    }
  }
```

Но ничего не выводит `alert`.  В чём проблема?

Comment: Потому `i = 0` всегда МЕНЬШЕ длины массива, а в условии стоит что нужно БОЛЬШЕ, поэтому цикл вообще ни разу не запускается. Но даже несмотря на это решение всё равно неправильное, потому что, если исправить условие, оно будет выводить много раз `yes` и много раз `no`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты делаешь вывод для каждого числа в массиве. В случае нахождения подходящей пары надо прекращать проверку. А для неподходящих пар вообще ничего делать не надо.

```js
function check(a) {
  for (var q=1; q<a.length; ++q) {
    if (a[q] === a[q-1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log(check([3, 1, 1, 12]) ? "Да" : "Нет");
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
[3, 1, 1, 12].reduce((a, b) => (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && a === b ? console.info('Yes') : null, b), null);
```

Comment: Вопрос в комментарии к другому ответу по прежнему остается философским. :)  Ибо `typeof Infinity === 'number'` и `typeof NaN === 'number'`, но при этом `Infinity === Infinity`, а `NaN !==  NaN`.

Comment: Я продолжаю настаивать что конкретные проверки не являются частью ответа на вопрос. Потому что тогда надо узнать как разработан IO, где можно встроить единую точку фильтрации, добавить новые типы вроде `int[]`, что отфильтрует массив целых и т. д.

Comment: Да понятно, что главное - идея. Но обратить внимание на тонкость, приводящую к не самому очевидному поведению в определенных случаях, тоже ведь стоит. :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
// Дословно:
// Существует ли элемент(не являющийся первым) равный предыдущему?
const hasSeqEq = arr => arr.some((el, i, arr) => i!=0 && el===arr[i-1]);

console.log(hasSeqEq([5, 1, 5, 2])); // false
console.log(hasSeqEq([5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 7])); // true
```

Преимущество `some` перед `reduce` заключается в том, что, если будет найдено совпадение, результат будет получен сразу же, не завершая прохода всего массива.

---

ES5:

```js
// Дословно:
// Существует ли элемент(не являющийся первым) равный предыдущему?
function hasSeqEq(arr) {
  return arr.some(function(el, i, arr) {
    return i != 0 && el === arr[i - 1];
  });
}

console.log(hasSeqEq([5, 1, 5, 2])); // false
console.log(hasSeqEq([5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 7])); // true
```

Comment: А если автору надо найти все совпадения о_О?

Comment: @Other, а если автору нужно ракету в космос запустить? Вы текст вопроса читали?

Comment: А если нужно биореактор запустить? В тексте прямо не указано что именно один раз вывести, а совпадений может быть больше. Хотя я, конечно, придираюсь :)

Comment: Позвольте узнать - зачем в `callback` определять массив, если он и так есть, под тем же названием (`arr`)?

Comment: Не определять, а использовать - он передаётся в callback в любом случае. Использовать его или ссылаться на внешний - вкусовщина. Я предпочитаю использовать локальный - это избавит callback от лишней зависимости и я смогу вынести его куда-нибудь при рефакторинге не изменяя. `Pure functional - наше всё`

Comment: Тут, кстати, возникает философский вопрос, что нужно возвращать, если в массиве окажется два подряд `NaN`. :)

Comment: @Yaant, Никакого вопроса нет - `NaN` не равны друг другу, а расшифровка: `Not a Number`, а мы ищем числа. Любопытно, но никто не проверил в своих ответах что значения - это цифры, т. е. `['a', 'a', 5, 1, 5, 2]` легко пройдёт проверку.

Comment: @Other Ну вот и я о том же :) Проверки на числа нет, а `undefined`'ы все равны, `null`'ы равны, `Infinity` равны, а `NaN`'ы вдруг нет. :)

Comment: Это уже на совести конечного реализатора. Идей накидали, а дальше уже сам :)

Comment: `Дан массив с числами.` - этого достаточно

Comment: @vp_arth Но формально, `NaN` - это такое специальное число. :) Во всяком случае `typeof NaN` возвращает `number`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function f(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) !== arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 8];
console.log(f(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы написали неправильное условие выхода из цикла.
`i > arr.length` - возвращает false на первой же проверке и цикл заканчивается не сделав ни одной итерации.

```js
var arr = [3, 1, 1, 12]; 

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (arr[i] === arr[j]){
            alert('yes')
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
    }
}
```